# Options for custom serializers / deserializers with Dropwizard?

Tags: jersey, jackson, dropwizard, jersey-client

What's a good way to have custom (de)serializers that can be registered externally with dropwizard?

I was having problems with (de)serializing a composite object. I tried using `@JsonUnwrapped` to get the JSON I wanted, but had problems with it for deserializing - it needs special constructors that take strings and requires the composite object to have knowledge on constructing the encapsulated objects. Also, I'd like a way of not having to use Jackson annotations on my value objects.

For example, I have:

```
public class SubmissionModule extends SimpleModule {
    public SubmissionModule() {
        addDeserializer(SubmissionDetails.class, new SubmissionDeserializer());
        addSerializer(SubmissionDetails.class, new SubmissionSerializer());
    }

    public class SubmissionSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SubmissionDetails> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(SubmissionDetails value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("id", "" + value.getId());
            jgen.writeStringField("title", value.getTitle());
            jgen.writeStringField("abstract", value.getAbstract());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }

    public class SubmissionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SubmissionDetails> {
        @Override
        public SubmissionDetails deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            return aSubmissionWithId(SubmissionId.from(node.get("id").asText()))
                    .title(node.get("title").asText())
                    .abstract_(node.get("abstract").asText()).create();
        }
    }
}
```

which I've registered in DropWizard like so:
`bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new SubmissionModule());`

but I can't figure out if it's possible to register the (de)serializers with the Jersey Client (or the client available when using `ResourceTestRule`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "but I can't figure out if it's possible to register the (de)serializers with the Jersey Client (or the client available when using ResourceTestRule). "

Check out the [source code for ResourceTestRule](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-testing/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/testing/junit/ResourceTestRule.java). There's a method `setMapper(ObjectMapper)`

You can do something like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new SubmissionModule());
@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule RULE 
           = new ResourceTestRule.Builder().setMapper(mapper).addResource(...).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get your information on `@JsonUnwrapped`, but it does not require special constructors or dependencies between containing and encapsulated object. Otherwise it would not really add much of use.
The annotation simply indicates that Object referred to should be written as a sequence of properties (in parent object), and not as Object value.
Not saying it will necessarily work for your use case, but you may have seen bad sample code or something.

As to avoiding annotations in value objects: one way to do that is to use "mix-in annotations" (http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-mix-in-annotation.jsp).
With that, you could use `@JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)` and `@JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class)` to indicate handlers to use.

Registering custom (de)serializers is handled by implementing a `Module` (usually just construct or sub-class `SimpleModule`), and registering that with `ObjectMapper` that DropWizard uses.

Comment: With `@JsonUnwrapped`,  the problem I was having (`"No _valueDeserializer assigned"` exception) was solved by setting a prefix. `@JsonUnwrapped(prefix="submission.")`.